# Query a DATETIME object for items from last week

Tags: sql, sqlite

Have a sqlite database with a `created` field that is a DATETIME kind.

I'm able to pull all items from the db created in the past 60 days with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where created >= date('now' , '-60 day')
```

I want a query that will pull all items only from last week, Sunday to Saturday. How would I structure such a query?

Comment: Do you want mysql or sqlite?

Comment: sorry, I want sqlite, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Using [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) you can retrieve the day of week. So subtracting that number from the current date will give you last Sunday's date (or today if it's Sunday).

```
select date('now' , (select '-' || strftime('%w', date('now')) || ' days'))
```

You can use this as a base for going back even further. For example, this query will give you the date of the Sunday before the most recent Sunday.

```
select date('now' ,
    (select
        '-'
        || (cast(strftime('%w', date('now')) as integer) + 7)
        || ' days'
    ))
```

So with some basic maths you can build the date range you want.

Comment: would this give me all 7 days last week?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "last week". Above query will give you the date of the most recent Sunday. I'll add some more info to the answer.